# I want to convert string ( which contain array of float values ) into float array in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i printed variable and it's  type in console I got following o/p.

```js
console.log(array);
console.log(typeof array);
```

```
[-0.20074345  0.17205992  0.10611761 -0.05400428  0.01761392 -0.02889173
 -0.02301165  0.02264201  0.14304711 -0.01270375  0.12890713 -0.07083786
 -0.16351621 -0.10163811 -0.00238512  0.11788289 -0.16991724 -0.18428595
 -0.07542907 -0.1000075   0.0540689   0.02885393 -0.02544132  0.00992649
 -0.14298916 -0.35953391 -0.04501984 -0.16696566  0.03482476 -0.12809309
 -0.00494457 -0.03969483 -0.20044276 -0.02079746 -0.0428996   0.08433075
  0.01925042 -0.05510717  0.1244439  -0.00250635 -0.09836875 -0.02853961
  0.0347203   0.32151613  0.15131931  0.03381695 -0.01653017 -0.02396783
  0.05017283 -0.15214115  0.09659076  0.11705139  0.06577846  0.08330107
  0.10685007 -0.12960862  0.03072787 -0.04441368 -0.23768349  0.00972465
 -0.01230429  0.01334048 -0.08945481 -0.05727607  0.23321879  0.1306915
 -0.04987631 -0.16629016  0.19155866 -0.12205004  0.02197403  0.02836045
 -0.07212473 -0.07092203 -0.22874205  0.06980464  0.36526302  0.08318733
 -0.19271423  0.05348996 -0.12581617 -0.10200049  0.01825046  0.01343039
 -0.16283956  0.11140806 -0.10517029  0.09450665  0.13496454  0.01246606
 -0.05901476  0.08878441  0.01477766 -0.07605766  0.08017815 -0.02794793
 -0.11664257  0.01248038 -0.14993706 -0.08350047  0.09859181 -0.10223893
 -0.06312436  0.11509642 -0.15772626  0.10087827  0.1003866  -0.08574189
 -0.06877069  0.10180675 -0.15567036 -0.0904673   0.14713711 -0.19140017
  0.14492355  0.13951159  0.0426133   0.14236017  0.04866033  0.09195794
 -0.02404636  0.03078505 -0.09961188 -0.03846828  0.03835503  0.07761194
  0.05843619  0.10325849]

string
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JSON.parse(array.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ','));
```

```js
const array = '[-0.20074345 0.17205992 0.10611761 -0.05400428 0.01761392 -0.02889173 -0.02301165 0.02264201 0.14304711 -0.01270375 0.12890713 -0.07083786 -0.16351621 -0.10163811 -0.00238512 0.11788289 -0.16991724 -0.18428595 -0.07542907 -0.1000075 0.0540689 0.02885393 -0.02544132 0.00992649 -0.14298916 -0.35953391 -0.04501984 -0.16696566 0.03482476 -0.12809309 -0.00494457 -0.03969483 -0.20044276 -0.02079746 -0.0428996 0.08433075 0.01925042 -0.05510717 0.1244439 -0.00250635 -0.09836875 -0.02853961 0.0347203 0.32151613 0.15131931 0.03381695 -0.01653017 -0.02396783 0.05017283 -0.15214115 0.09659076 0.11705139 0.06577846 0.08330107 0.10685007 -0.12960862 0.03072787 -0.04441368 -0.23768349 0.00972465 -0.01230429 0.01334048 -0.08945481 -0.05727607 0.23321879 0.1306915 -0.04987631 -0.16629016 0.19155866 -0.12205004 0.02197403 0.02836045 -0.07212473 -0.07092203 -0.22874205 0.06980464 0.36526302 0.08318733 -0.19271423 0.05348996 -0.12581617 -0.10200049 0.01825046 0.01343039 -0.16283956 0.11140806 -0.10517029 0.09450665 0.13496454 0.01246606 -0.05901476 0.08878441 0.01477766 -0.07605766 0.08017815 -0.02794793 -0.11664257 0.01248038 -0.14993706 -0.08350047 0.09859181 -0.10223893 -0.06312436 0.11509642 -0.15772626 0.10087827 0.1003866 -0.08574189 -0.06877069 0.10180675 -0.15567036 -0.0904673 0.14713711 -0.19140017 0.14492355 0.13951159 0.0426133 0.14236017 0.04866033 0.09195794 -0.02404636 0.03078505 -0.09961188 -0.03846828 0.03835503 0.07761194 0.05843619 0.10325849]';

const result = JSON.parse(array.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ','));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are smart !

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1465                                    JSON.parse(array.replace(/\s+/g, ","));   error occured at between .Parse

Comment: @SaurabhDhakne Probably because there are white spaces somewhere, try the updated function

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Just try to remove the brackets from the string:

```
var array = '[-0.20074345 0.17205992 0.10611761 -0.05400428 0.01761392 -0.02889173 -0.02301165 0.02264201 0.14304711 -0.01270375 0.12890713 -0.07083786 -0.16351621 -0.10163811 -0.00238512 0.11788289 -0.16991724 -0.18428595 -0.07542907 -0.1000075 0.0540689 0.02885393 -0.02544132 0.00992649 -0.14298916 -0.35953391 -0.04501984 -0.16696566 0.03482476 -0.12809309 -0.00494457 -0.03969483 -0.20044276 -0.02079746 -0.0428996 0.08433075 0.01925042 -0.05510717 0.1244439 -0.00250635 -0.09836875 -0.02853961 0.0347203 0.32151613 0.15131931 0.03381695 -0.01653017 -0.02396783 0.05017283 -0.15214115 0.09659076 0.11705139 0.06577846 0.08330107 0.10685007 -0.12960862 0.03072787 -0.04441368 -0.23768349 0.00972465 -0.01230429 0.01334048 -0.08945481 -0.05727607 0.23321879 0.1306915 -0.04987631 -0.16629016 0.19155866 -0.12205004 0.02197403 0.02836045 -0.07212473 -0.07092203 -0.22874205 0.06980464 0.36526302 0.08318733 -0.19271423 0.05348996 -0.12581617 -0.10200049 0.01825046 0.01343039 -0.16283956 0.11140806 -0.10517029 0.09450665 0.13496454 0.01246606 -0.05901476 0.08878441 0.01477766 -0.07605766 0.08017815 -0.02794793 -0.11664257 0.01248038 -0.14993706 -0.08350047 0.09859181 -0.10223893 -0.06312436 0.11509642 -0.15772626 0.10087827 0.1003866 -0.08574189 -0.06877069 0.10180675 -0.15567036 -0.0904673 0.14713711 -0.19140017 0.14492355 0.13951159 0.0426133 0.14236017 0.04866033 0.09195794 -0.02404636 0.03078505 -0.09961188 -0.03846828 0.03835503 0.07761194 0.05843619 0.10325849]';

Array.from(array.substring(1, array.length-1).split(" "), Number)
```

Comment: op :- 0.20074345,           0,                                                                                    this is 1st two indexes of output getting 0 intead of that float value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using simple string and array operations.

```js
let arr = `[-0.20074345 0.17205992 0.10611761 -0.05400428 0.01761392 -0.02889173 -0.02301165 0.02264201 0.14304711 -0.01270375 0.12890713 -0.07083786 -0.16351621 -0.10163811 -0.00238512 0.11788289 -0.16991724 -0.18428595 -0.07542907 -0.1000075 0.0540689 0.02885393 -0.02544132 0.00992649 -0.14298916 -0.35953391 -0.04501984 -0.16696566 0.03482476 -0.12809309 -0.00494457 -0.03969483 -0.20044276 -0.02079746 -0.0428996 0.08433075 0.01925042 -0.05510717 0.1244439 -0.00250635 -0.09836875 -0.02853961 0.0347203 0.32151613 0.15131931 0.03381695 -0.01653017 -0.02396783 0.05017283 -0.15214115 0.09659076 0.11705139 0.06577846 0.08330107 0.10685007 -0.12960862 0.03072787 -0.04441368 -0.23768349 0.00972465 -0.01230429 0.01334048 -0.08945481 -0.05727607 0.23321879 0.1306915 -0.04987631 -0.16629016 0.19155866 -0.12205004 0.02197403 0.02836045 -0.07212473 -0.07092203 -0.22874205 0.06980464 0.36526302 0.08318733 -0.19271423 0.05348996 -0.12581617 -0.10200049 0.01825046 0.01343039 -0.16283956 0.11140806 -0.10517029 0.09450665 0.13496454 0.01246606 -0.05901476 0.08878441 0.01477766 -0.07605766 0.08017815 -0.02794793 -0.11664257 0.01248038 -0.14993706 -0.08350047 0.09859181 -0.10223893 -0.06312436 0.11509642 -0.15772626 0.10087827 0.1003866 -0.08574189 -0.06877069 0.10180675 -0.15567036 -0.0904673 0.14713711 -0.19140017 0.14492355 0.13951159 0.0426133 0.14236017 0.04866033 0.09195794 -0.02404636 0.03078505 -0.09961188 -0.03846828 0.03835503 0.07761194 0.05843619 0.10325849]`;

let convArray = arr.replace(/\[|\]/gi, '')
  .split(' ')
  .filter(v => v) // remove empty strings if present
  .map(v => Number(v));
console.log(convArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "['-6.35', '2.72', '-11.79', '183.25']",
  array = str.match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)
```

This should solve your issue. The regular expression matches all decimals and then by using .map(Number) the array will be created.

Comment: array = array.match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).map(Number);                                                                                                    Thank you so much this worked, I just replaced 'str' with 'array'

Comment: Glad it helped! ;) since you found the answer useful, vote it so that other people that have the same issue can more easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
const text = `[-0.20074345  0.17205992  0.10611761 -0.05400428  0.01761392 -0.02889173
 -0.02301165  0.02264201  0.14304711 -0.01270375  0.12890713 -0.07083786
 -0.16351621 -0.10163811 -0.00238512  0.11788289 -0.16991724 -0.18428595
 -0.07542907 -0.1000075   0.0540689   0.02885393 -0.02544132  0.00992649
 -0.14298916 -0.35953391 -0.04501984 -0.16696566  0.03482476 -0.12809309
 -0.00494457 -0.03969483 -0.20044276 -0.02079746 -0.0428996   0.08433075
  0.01925042 -0.05510717  0.1244439  -0.00250635 -0.09836875 -0.02853961
  0.0347203   0.32151613  0.15131931  0.03381695 -0.01653017 -0.02396783
  0.05017283 -0.15214115  0.09659076  0.11705139  0.06577846  0.08330107
  0.10685007 -0.12960862  0.03072787 -0.04441368 -0.23768349  0.00972465
 -0.01230429  0.01334048 -0.08945481 -0.05727607  0.23321879  0.1306915
 -0.04987631 -0.16629016  0.19155866 -0.12205004  0.02197403  0.02836045
 -0.07212473 -0.07092203 -0.22874205  0.06980464  0.36526302  0.08318733
 -0.19271423  0.05348996 -0.12581617 -0.10200049  0.01825046  0.01343039
 -0.16283956  0.11140806 -0.10517029  0.09450665  0.13496454  0.01246606
 -0.05901476  0.08878441  0.01477766 -0.07605766  0.08017815 -0.02794793
 -0.11664257  0.01248038 -0.14993706 -0.08350047  0.09859181 -0.10223893
 -0.06312436  0.11509642 -0.15772626  0.10087827  0.1003866  -0.08574189
 -0.06877069  0.10180675 -0.15567036 -0.0904673   0.14713711 -0.19140017
  0.14492355  0.13951159  0.0426133   0.14236017  0.04866033  0.09195794
 -0.02404636  0.03078505 -0.09961188 -0.03846828  0.03835503  0.07761194
  0.05843619  0.10325849]`;

const array = text.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '').split(/\s+/).map(Number);

console.log(array);
console.log(Array.isArray(array));
console.log(typeof array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert any string into expression you can use the eval function.

```
console.log(eval(array));
```

Will return the actual array of float instead of string. But make sure that format of array is correct inside the string.